# Symfony \ Component \ Debug \ Exception \ FatalErrorException syntax error, unexpected end of file (Laravel)

Tags: php, laravel

The master.blade.php's file contains:

```
@section('content')
  @foreach($admons as $admon)
    <p>{{ $admons->admon }}</p>
  @foreach
@stop
```

and it is throwing me the error:

```
Symfony \ Component \ Debug \ Exception \ FatalErrorException
syntax error, unexpected end of file
```

> C:\AppServ\www\Viniza\app\storage\views\b48f03c3d0a952af7b5dd24750898f94

```
 $(document).ready(function() {
$('ul.sf-menu').sooperfish();
$('.top').click(function() {$('html, body').animate({scrollTop:0}, 'fast'); return false;});
});
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

the full content of master.blade.php's file is:

```
{{ HTML::style('css/style.css') }}
{{ HTML::script('js/jquery.js') }}

@section('content')
  @foreach($admons as $admon)
    <p>{{ $admons->admon }}</p>
  @foreach
@stop

<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>

<head>
  <title>Viniza Konw</title>
  <meta name="keywords" content="coffee buy shop" />
  <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
</head>

<body>
  <div id="main">
    <header>
      <div id="logo">
        <div id="logo_text">
          <h1><a href="index.html">Coffe<span class="logo_colour">JuanValdez</span></a></h1>
        </div>
      </div>
      <nav>
        <div id="menu_container">
          <ul class="sf-menu" id="nav">
            <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </nav>
    </header>

    <div id="site_content">
      <div class="content">
        <h1></h1>

        <div class="header_image">
          {{ HTML::image('images/header_image.jpg', "Imagen no encontrada", 
            array('id' => 'center', 'title' => 'center')) }}
        </div>

        <div class="border_top"></div>
        <div class="border_bottom"></div>          

      </div>      
    </div>
    <div id="scroll">
      <a title="Scroll to the top" class="top" href="#"><img src="images/top.png" alt="top" /></a>
    </div>
    <footer>
      <p><img src="images/twitter.png" alt="twitter" />&nbsp;
         <img src="images/facebook.png" alt="facebook" />&nbsp;
         <img src="images/rss.png" alt="rss" />           </p>
      <p>Copyright &copy; CSS3_winter_scene | <a href="http://www.css3templates.co.uk">design from css3templates.co.uk</a></p>
    </footer>
  </div>
  <!-- javascript at the bottom for fast page loading -->
  <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.easing-sooper.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.sooperfish.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
      $('ul.sf-menu').sooperfish();
      $('.top').click(function() {$('html, body').animate({scrollTop:0}, 'fast'); return false;});
    });
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This error in Symphony is usually telling you that you didn't 'end' a control structure (i.e. an 'if' or 'foreach').

You have a couple typos, where you are ending your foreach with "@foreach" it should be "@endforeach".

That should do it for you.

Answer (score 1):

In my case, it was the silliest mistake. I missed out a `;` while creating a route with a closure function.

So, if you've not made any mistakes as pointed out by above 2 answers, look for any syntax error in your `routes\web.php` (Laravel 5.3+)

Answer (score 0):

I just ran into the same error and it was due to a GIT conflict.
So if the first answer doesn't fix the problem, look for "<<< HEAD" in your code